# Dart passing types to functions fails

Tags: dart, types, casting

I have a map consisting of different types and strings:

```dart
const Map<Type, String> hiveTableNames = {
  BreakTimeDto: "breaktime",
  WorkTimeDto: "worktime"
};
```

And I want to loop through it because I want to call a function for each type which takes a type parameter:

```dart
Future<void> sendAll<T>(List item) async {
...
}
```

My attempt was to use the forEach-loop:

```dart
hiveTableNames.forEach((key, value) async {
        final box = await Hive.openBox(value);
        _helper.sendAll<key>(box.values.cast<key>().toList());
      });
```

But the App throws an error: **Error: 'key' isn*t a type.**

Why is that? I declared the map to store types and from my understanding i pass these types in the function.

Comment: You have to pass the class type of `key` instead of passing a variable to to the `cast` method.

Comment: @AdnanAlshami how would I do that, due to the fact that the class type of key are always different class types, as seen in the map?

Comment: I believe that generics are resolved at compilation time; otherwise wouldn't get static type-checking of arguments or return values that depend on that generic type.  You therefore can't use a variable as a type parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart separates actual types and objects of type `Type`. The latter are not types, and cannot be used as types, they're more like *mirrors* of types. A `Type` object can only really be used for two things: as tokens to use with `dart:mirrors` and comparing for equality (which isn't particularly useful except for very simple types).

The only things that can be used as type arguments to generic functions or classes are actual literal types or other type variables.

In your case, you have a `Type` object and wants to use the corresponding type as a type argument. That won't work, there is no way to go from a `Type` object to a real type.
That's a deliberate choice, it means that the compiler can see that if a type is never used as a type argument in the source code, then it will never be the type bound to a type parameter, so if you have `foo<T>(T value) => ...` then you know that `T` will never be `Bar` if `Bar` doesn't occur as a type argument, `something<Bar>()`, anywhere in the program.

In your case, what you can do is to keep the type around *as a type* by using a more complicated key object.

Perhaps:

```dart
class MyType<T> {
  const MyType();
  R use<R>(R Function<X>() action) => action<T>();
  int get hashCode => T.hashCode;
  bool operator==(Object other) => other is MyType && other.use(<S>() => T == S);
}
```

This allows you to store the type *as a type*:

```dart
final Map<MyType, String> hiveTableNames = {
  const MyType<BreakTimeDto>(): "breaktime",
  const MyType<WorkTimeDto>(): "worktime"
};
```

(I'm not making the map `const` because `const` maps must not have keys which override `operator==`).
Then you can use it as:

```dart
hiveTableNames.forEach((key, value) async {
  final box = await Hive.openBox(value);
  key.use(<K>() => 
    _helper.sendAll<K>([for (var v in box.values) v as K]);
}
```

(If all you are using your map for is iterating the key/value pairs, then it's really just a list of pairs, not a map, so I assume you are using it for lookups, which is why `MyType` override `operator==`).

In general, you should avoid using `Type` objects for anything, they're very rarely the right tool for any job.